# Cannot be applied to

Tags: types, enums

Ingredient() in Ingredient cannot be applied to:

Expected: Actual
Parameters: Arguments: "FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Ingredient.Type.WRAP

Included all needed imports

Here the Ingredient class:

```
package com.taco.cloud.other;


import lombok.Data;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Ingredient {


    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final Type type;

    public Ingredient() {
        name = null;
        id = null;
        type = null;
    }

    public static enum Type{
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE}
}
```

And here DesingTacoController class:

```
package com.taco.cloud.controllers;


import com.taco.cloud.other.Ingredient;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import com.taco.cloud.other.Ingredient.Type;

@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/desing")
public class DesignTacoController {


    @GetMapping
    public String showDesignForm(Model model){
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
                new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Ingredient.Type.WRAP),
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to Ingredient class does not have getter & setters and constructor. Problem was concerned with Lombok.